# How to add a background text to textarea tags?

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

You know that you can add an image as a background image for textarea using :

```
textarea {
 background:#fff url(background.png) no-repeat center scroll; 
}
```

How can I have text (not image, nor text as an image) as a background for textarea ?

**It isn't the text contained in the textarea itself**. It is some text behind. The user can write in the textarea, and, just like the background image, see the background text behind.

CSS2 preferred, CSS3 and js are OK.

Comment: Don't think you can add background text to any element.

Comment: Thanks for the guy who advised to use the textarea's placeholder attribute. It isn't the answer to the question, but it's a cool trick to know and use !! (you can check it there :http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_placeholder)

Comment: @Cedrice `placeholder` and `background-image` are nowhere related also you mentioned _see the background text behind_ in OP. `placeholder` goes off when the textarea is focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a brute force approach:

```
<div class="wallpapered">
    <div class="background">Some background text...</div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.wallpapered {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
.wallpapered textarea {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
.wallpapered .background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: gray;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/4ZDUB/)

Answer (score 12):

How about the placeholder attribute:

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="enter optional message"></textarea>
```

Comment: IMO you can use placeholder attribute and use a JS tool to fill in for unsupported browser. If you are using jQuery in your project you might wana use something like http://andrew-jones.com/jquery-placeholder-plugin/

Comment: Yeah definitely, there are a lot of placeholder polyfills like this one: https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill.  @Mindbreaker, not sure what isn't correct, caniuse verifies that it isn't supported at all in current releases of IE.

Comment: @jason but the whole "current" line is green. That means it is widely supported.

Comment: You go by that and you eliminate the support for everyone using IE7, 8, and 9.  I agreed earlier that polyfills can help this, but it doesn't change the fact that they aren't supported.  Believe it or not, not everyone has the latest browser.  Besides that, the placeholder element doesn't quite answer his question.  The point of placeholder isn't for a background, it's to replace the onblur/onfocus hack that devs used for placeholders before.  The placeholder text will disappear once the textfield is focused on, not remain in the background.

Comment: This is only one solution i want to share with the questioner. But if you give a comment and say "this isn't widely supported" is this a wrong assertion.

Comment: The placeholder disappears if there is text entered in the text area, so that is not quite the same as having a background.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a div and positioning DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/UXgJD/1/

```
textarea {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only way I could think to do it would be to manually place some text there with a fixed position.

[JS-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpEsv/)

HTML:

```
 <textarea>This is text</textarea>
 <div class="bgtext">
     this is background text
 </div>
```

CSS for the Div (background text):

```
 .bgtext {
     position: fixed;
     top: 15px;
     left:10px;
     opacity: 0.4; /*optional*/
 }
```